# Display language of current user (in English) using Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

Some Windows computers have multiple display languages installed.

I can get the current user's UI language in that language using the function:

```
function GetUsersWindowsLanguage: string;
var
  WinLanguage: array [0..50] of char;
begin
  VerLanguageName(GetUserDefaultUILanguage, WinLanguage, 50);
  Result := WinLanguage;
end;
```

This function outputs something like this:

```
Espagnol (Espagne)
```

The output is not in English. All I need is "Spanish". Is there any way to get the display language in English?

I'm using Delphi 10.3.3 (VCL application).

Comment: Could be impossible if the system doesn't have English at all. Why not going with the ID that `GetUserDefaultUILanguage()` gives you? "Spanish (Spain)" would equal `$0c0a` (or more generic `$0A`) as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-lcid/70feba9f-294e-491e-b6eb-56532684c37f

Comment: @AmigoJack Apparently LOCALE_SENGLISHDISPLAYNAME provides in English. Problem solved.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```pascal
function GetUsersWindowsLanguage: string;
var
  WinLanguage: array [0..50] of char;
begin
  GetLocaleInfoW(GetUserDefaultUILanguage, LOCALE_SENGLISHDISPLAYNAME, WinLanguage, 50);
  Result := WinLanguage;
end;
```

Comment: You are a hero!

Comment: And this is guaranteed to work on all systems? Also those that have no English installed?

Comment: For the record, it works on Windows 7 and later. XP and Vista fail. @AmigoJack Windows 7+ doesn't require English installed.